What current can an FS32K148UJT0VLQT GPIO source?
I am using an FS32K148UJT0VLQT in my design. I was trying to see the maximum current the GPIO can source.
My board is working at 5V. The DC electrical specifications at 5V is given below. Minimum value is provided, but maximum value is not given.

Where can I find the maximum value?
What will happen if I take 40mA from any GPIO?



Side note: if you really need 40 mA, you can possibly connect GPIOs in parallel. Whether this is possible or not depends on the specifics of the chip you are using.

For what purpose you need this value, what are you trying to do with the current, why would you need more than 20mA out of an IO pin anyway, and even that spec assumes 5V supply, it's less for 3.3V supply.

NXP Community

The other answers say that 20mA is the maximum, but more specifically, as per the data sheet, it is not the maximum, you can draw more, but 20mA is the minimum guaranteed output current in the condition that supply voltage is 5.0V and output pin voltage is VDD-0.8V, or 800mV less than supply voltage, and that is under the whole specified temperature range.
So it does not mean that 20mA is the maximum, you can draw more but then the voltage will drop more than 800mV from supply, and please note that even with the 20mA current, the output isn't your 5V supply but it could be up to 800mV less than 5V supply.
The point is that if you try to draw more current than 20mA, you are not given a value how much voltage drop you can expect. So if you do, you should characterize it yourself or if you are big enough customer, just ask the manufacturer about the data. They likely don't know and politely decline to characterize it for you.
If you need to drive a heavy load like LEDs or relay and need more current, use transistor or load switch or enable a regulator IC with the GPIO pin. It is generally not a good idea to waste power inside the MCU just because you want to drive a huge load directly with GPIO.
Even at the rated max 800mV drop at 20mA, the tiny PFET inside the MCU locally heats up with 16 milliwatts and the 20mA current will cause drops in the narrow wiring inside the MCU.
Assuming max 800mV drop at 20mA, the PFET has output impedance of 40 ohms.
And you can't output more than 100mA total from the IO ports anyway, due to internal structures.
The actual absolute maximum value is not stated anywhere, usually it is, for the sake of knowing that if you accidentally shorted it and some amount of current passed, did it exceed some limit of damage and you should not trust the MCU being OK any more.

As shown in the question the documentation for the FS32K only specifies the minimum of the max current. The reason is that this is the critical value for designing a circuit around this pin.
Everything above this value is a gamble you want to avoid.
E.g. a batch of these controllers might have a few GPIOs that are able to source 30 mA in the same conditions.
But the next batch does not. A circuit designed for 30 mA will not behave optimal with the second batch. The output voltage will not reach the on voltage that the IOs are supposed to provide, which could mean faulty communication.
Please also note that these 20 mA are only for pins where high drive strength has been activated. This has to be done in the code. Elsewise you will only get a guaranteed minimal current of 5 mA.
Also important to check: Some pins might not support the high drive strength at all.
The total current sourced or sinked through the pins has an additional limit. The limit can be for thermal reasons or because the internal voltage drop could bring the MCU close to a brownout.

The specified current is the guaranteed current that each I/O pin is able to source or sink.
Individual exemplars will for sure be able to source/sink more, but these values are not the same among all delivered MCUs. Additionally the current depends on temperature, age, supply voltage, and so on.
Your design shall use no more than the specified current. If it uses more, you operate the MCU outside the specification.
In the same table is the maximum current for all I/Os together:

IOHT (Output high current total for all ports) = 100 mA.

If you try to take 40 mA, the I/O pin will raise its voltage loss, to the extend that your load will not receive any voltage. The exact value is not specified, it can be any current above 20 mA, and may well be clearly below 40 mA.

The term "source (or sink) capability" implies the maximum guaranteed value, and the fact that this figure appears in the "minimum" column, leads me to interpret this figure as follows:
The current that this pin is able to source or sink is at least 20mA, probably more. However, they only guarantee 20mA.
